# How to reset timer I've created in Angular on click?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm creating a small app which keeps track of what activity I've done in a certain timespan once I write down said activity inside of an input field, once I click "OK" it should appear in a list.

I'm stuck on how I should proceed to reset the timer once I click the "OK" button, so basically what I should add inside the "resetTimer()" function which is supposed to trigger each time I add a task in a list.

HTML:

```html
<div class="modalbox" [class.active]="modalboxActive">
  <div class="modal">
    <p>What did you do?</p>

    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="activity.name" />
    <button (click)="addTask()" [disabled]="activity.name === ''">OK</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="boxSuper">
  <div class="boxLeft">
    <div class="containerUp">
      <button id="start" (click)="startTimer()">START</button>
      <button id="pause" (click)="pauseTimer()">PAUSE</button>
      <button id="stop" (click)="stopTimer()">STOP</button>
    </div>
    <div class="containerDown">
      <p>{{ display }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="boxRight">
    <div class="containerLeft"></div>
    <div class="containerRight">
      <ul class="listElement" *ngFor="let item of tasks">
        <li>
          Activity:
          <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
          Length:
          <span>{{ item.length }}</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

TS:

```js
import { importExpr } from '@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { timer } from 'rxjs';
import { Activity } from '../activity';
import { Result } from '../result';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-timer',
  templateUrl: './timer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./timer.component.css'],
})
export class TimerComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {}
  time: number = 0;
  display: string | undefined;
  interval: any;
  modalboxActive = false;

  activity: Activity = {
    name: '',
  };

  tasks: Result[] = [];

  addTask() {
    var el: Result = {
      name: this.activity.name,
      end: '',
      start: '',
      length: this.display,
    };

    this.tasks.push(el);
    this.activity.name = '';
    this.modalboxActive = false;
    this.resetTimer();
  }

  resetTimer() {
    console.log('reset');
  }

  startTimer() {
    console.log('go');
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (this.time === 0) {
        this.time++;
      } else {
        this.time++;
      }
      this.display = this.transform(this.time);
    }, 1000);
  }
  transform(value: number): string {
    var sec_num = value;
    var hours = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
    var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - hours * 3600) / 60);
    var seconds = sec_num - hours * 3600 - minutes * 60;
    return hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
  }
  pauseTimer() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
  stopTimer() {
    this.modalboxActive = true;
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    console.log('show');
  }
}
```

Result interface:

```js
export interface Result {
  start: string | undefined;
  end: string | undefined;
  length: string | undefined;
  name: string | undefined;
}
```

Comment: Just as a quick heads-up: `setInterval` as well as `setTimeout` do not have any accuracy guarantees. It might take a tad longer or less for each new execution of your callback. A better approach than to "count upwards" each second is to store the point in time when `startTimer` was executed as well as `stopTimer` and just compare the delta between the two timestamps.
Other than that @Skelly provided you with a sufficient answer! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to just reset it back to 0, all you would need to do is:

```
resetTimer(){
   this.time = 0;
}
```